# How to Train a Decoder for Pre-trained BERT Transformer-Encoder?

Tags: transformer, bert, pretrained-models, seq2seq, encoder-decoder

**Context:**
I am currently working on an encoder-decoder sequence to sequence model that uses a sequence of word embeddings as input and output, and then reduces the dimensionality of the word embeddings.

The word embeddings are created using pre-trained models. I want to be able to decode the word embeddings returned by the decoder of the Sequence to Sequence model back to natural language.

**Question:** How can I train a Decoder that works with the sequence of word embeddings and the original sentence for this task?

See below for the code that generates the word embeddings:

````
from typing import List

import numpy as np
import torch
from transformers.tokenization_utils_base import BatchEncoding
from transformers import BertTokenizerFast, BertModel

TOKENIZER = BertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
MODEL = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

def get_word_indices(sentence: str, separator=" ") -> List:
    sent = sentence.split(sep=separator)
    return list(range(len(sent)))

def encode_sentence(sentence: str) -> BatchEncoding:
    encoded_sentence = TOKENIZER(sentence)
    return encoded_sentence

def get_hidden_states(encoded: BatchEncoding, layers: list = [-1, -2, -3, -4]) -> torch.Tensor:
    with torch.no_grad():
        output = MODEL(**encoded)
    hidden_states = output.hidden_states
    output = torch.stack([hidden_states[i] for i in layers]).sum(0).squeeze()
    return output

def get_token_ids(word_index: int, encoded: BatchEncoding):
    token_ids = np.where(np.array(encoded.word_ids()) == word_index)
    return token_ids

def embed_words(sentence: str) -> torch.Tensor:
    word_indices = get_word_indices(sentence)
    encoded_sentence = encode_sentence(sentence)
    hidden_states = get_hidden_states(encoded_sentence)
    word_embeddings = []
    for word_index in word_indices:
        # Get the ids of the word in the sentence
        # Important, because BERT sometimes splits words into subwords
        token_ids = get_token_ids(word_index, encoded_sentence)
        # Get all the hidden states for each word (or subwords belonging to one word)
        # Average the hidden states in case of subwords to retrieve word embedding
        word_embedding = hidden_states[token_ids].mean(dim=0)
        word_embeddings.append(word_embedding)
    return torch.stack(word_embeddings)
```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this example code https://github.com/microsoft/CodeBERT/blob/master/CodeBERT/code2nl/README.md

This example generally loads pre-trained Bert (encoder) and plugs a custom decoder. Regarding its encoder, the example utilizes `transformer` for loading pre-train.